# Redux ES6 (BabelJS): is there a map function that can iterate this structure?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, babeljs

```
{
            '1': {
                id: 1,
                parent_id: 0,
                elementType: 'view',
                style: {color: 'green'},
                selected: false,
                childIds: [2]
            },
            '2': {
                id: 2,
                parent_id: 1,
                elementType: 'text',
                style: {color: 'green'},
                selected: true,
                childIds: []
            }
```

}

It's for a reducer and I'd love to be able to do this:

```
obj.map(([key, value])=> {
    if (value.id === 1) {
        return {...value, selected:false};
    } else {
        return value;
    }
});
```

I thought maybe using [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) but it will probably won't play well with redux mapping.

**UPDATE:**

Following the recommendation here I've tried building a new map function. This version is what I came with:

```
const map = (object, callback) => {
    return Object.keys(object).reduce(function(output, key) {

        output[key] = callback.call(this, object[key]);

        return output;
    }, {});
}
```

And I a trying to use it like this (an example):

```
let newState = map(oldState, element => {
    if (element.id === 1) {
        return {...element, selected:false};
    } else {
        return {...element};
    }
});
```

Meanwhile the tests are passing.

Comment: you can give it a `length` property and `apply()` `[].map()`, or write your own version of map(). looks like a good use case for `for-of` though...

Comment: I am writing tests. is writing my own version of map a good approach for tests?

Comment: imho, it doesn't matter where tested code comes from, just how it tests out. you could also use a simple tool to turn an object of objects into an array of objects, then use whatever on that real array

Answer (score 1):

Try using Object.keys(), it will let you traverse through object keys, that way you will be able to access specific value.

Comment: I am looking for a map-like method to return a new object as I want to return a newState for Redux

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `Object.entries`. It's still a proposal, but I think it's already hidden behind some babel stage flag.

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    //do whatever you want
}
```

[ES proposal: Object.entries() and Object.values()](http://www.2ality.com/2015/11/stage3-object-entries.html)

Comment: I am looking for a map-like method to return a new object as I want to return a newState for Redux that is why I used reduce